# Oracle CTE/subquery factoring delete

Tags: sql, oracle

```
WITH RemoveDate As (
SELECT table.*, ROW_NUMBER()
OVER (PARTITION BY id order by row_added_dttm) AS RowNumber 
FROM table
WHERE (grp = '124') 
and row_added_dttm <= (SELECT MAX(row_added_dttm) from table
 where (grp = '124') )
) 
delete from RemoveDate where RowNumber >1
```

Hello i need to run it on Oracle SQL Developer but it doesnt work. I have duplications and i need to delete one and another one have to be still in database. Ofc not all are duplications and they need to be deleted too. I need to have only newest row for one id.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`MERGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93054/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, row_added_dttm ) AS
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-09-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-09-19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-09-18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-09-17' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2017-09-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2017-09-18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, DATE '2017-09-15' FROM DUAL;

MERGE INTO table_name t
USING (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY row_added_dttm DESC )
           AS RN,
         ROWID AS rid
  FROM   table_name
) m
ON ( t.ROWID = m.ROWID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET id = id
  DELETE WHERE m.RN > 1;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93054/1/0)**:

```
| ID |       ROW_ADDED_DTTM |
|----|----------------------|
|  1 | 2017-09-20T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | 2017-09-20T00:00:00Z |
|  3 | 2017-09-15T00:00:00Z |
```